# Unity IL2CPP Android build crashes Mac

Tags: android, macos, unity-game-engine, il2cpp

When trying to build a Google App Bundle, every time the process gets to the step that says Building Native Binaries With IL2CPP I get a “Your system has run out of application memory” error and my MacBook reboots.

The project built no problem on Mono, but now that Google is demanding a 64 bit version, that’s not an alternative.

I’m running Unity 2019.2.2.  MacOS Mojave.  I have a new MacBook Pro with 16GB of RAM.  So, I don’t think it’s a hardware issue.

I’ve done everything I can find in the forums.  My Java is the right version, I have the NDK version that Unity 2019 requires.  I’ve tried every solution I can find online.

Comment: Could you add the [Editor logs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html) with the crash information so we can have more context to help you?

Comment: The editor is not crashing and it’s log shows no errors at all.  I get the pop up from Mojave saying my system is out of application memory and it forces the reboot.  That’s why I can’t figure out what’s happening because as far as Unity is concerned there is no error.  I had the same issue when first attempting to build for iOS and switching from the .Net 4x to .Net 2.0 solved it there, but I’ve tried both on the Android build and neither will finish

Comment: Javier - thanks for the willingness to assist.  I have solved the issue.  I'm building a word game and I had initially hard coded all of my acceptable words with a List<string> for each letter because I was not planning to incorporate a database into the app.  Some of them, like S had almost 20K words on the list.  I did eventually end up adding a database for other reasons.  After reading this post https://answers.unity.com/questions/1508131/il2cpp-freeze-while-exporting-android-project-in-u.html I decided to go back and covert those to database tables.  Doing so allowed a successful build.

Comment: Glad that you could fix it. And thanks for telling how your problem was fixed! 
Sorry that I couldn't be of more help.